# Scala Spark count regex matches in a file

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I am learning Spark+Scala and I am stuck with this problem. I have one file that contains many sentences, and another file with a large number of regular expressions. Both files have one element per line.

What I want is to count how many times each regex has a match in the whole sentences file. For example if the sentences file (after becoming an array or list) was represented by `["hello world and hello life", "hello i m fine", "what is your name"]`,  and the regex files by `["hello \\w+", "what \\w+ your", ...]` then I would like the output to be something like: `[("hello \\w+", 3),("what \\w+ your",1), ...]`

My code is like this:

```
object PatternCount_v2 {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // The text where we will find the patterns
    val inputFile = args(0);
    // The list of patterns 
    val inputPatterns = args(1)
    val outputPath = args(2);

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // Load the text file
    val textFile = sc.textFile(inputFile).cache()
    // Load the patterns
    val patterns = Source.fromFile(inputPatterns).getLines.map(line => line.r).toList

    val patternCounts = textFile.flatMap(line => {
        println(line)
        patterns.foreach(
            pattern => {
                println(pattern)
                (pattern,pattern.findAllIn(line).length )

            }
        )
    }

    )
    patternCounts.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)


}}
```

But the compiler complains:

[image]

If I change the flatMap to just map the code runs but returns a bunch of empty tuples () () () ()

Please help! This is driving me crazy.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, there are two issues here:

1. You should use `map` instead of `foreach`: `foreach` returns `Unit`, it performs an action with a potential *side effect* on each element of a collection, it doesn't return a new collection. `map` on the other hand transform a collection into a new one by applying the supplied function to each element
2. You're missing the part where you *aggregate* the results of `flatMap` to get the actual count per "key" (pattern). This can be done easily with `reduceByKey`

Altogether - this does what you need:

```
val patternCounts = textFile
  .flatMap(line => patterns.map(pattern => (pattern, pattern.findAllIn(line).length)))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Comment: Just perfect! Thanks for bringing me back from my frustration.